Why does northeastern Asia have dry winters?
Northeastern mainland Asia such as northeastern China, North Korea, most of South Korea and parts of Siberia are classified as a Dwx climate, meaning they have dry winters. Why is this despite being at or near the Pacific coast and why is northeastern Asia the only large region on Earth having Dw-type sea level climates?

My hunch after looking at current models, SSTs, and topo would be that it's connected to the Stanovor and Yabonovyy ranges in Russia to the north, which run west-east.  Being high mid-latitude, the wind flow should predominantly be from the north/northwest/west during the winter... meaning they don't get winds brining effects from the Pacific much at all. Very similar to the Canadian/northern US Plains into the eastern lowlands/Great Lakes regions... except the key zonal mountain range. The flow over those mountains should wring out more of the moisture, leading to drier winters to the S\SE\E.
